# Restlet code works on local but not when deployed (on Openshift)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, openshift, restlet, capedwarf

Hello I am having this problem where this code:

```
public class FirstStepsApplication extends Application {
    private static final String ROOT_URI = "/";
    @Override
    public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        Directory rootDir = new Directory(getContext(), "war:///doc");
        rootDir.setIndexName("index.html");
        router.attach(ROOT_URI, rootDir);
        return router;
    }
}
```

Works in GAE localhost, when run with Maven: `$mvn appengine:devserver`

No problem. However when deployed it does not work anymore. I've checked the logs and all I can see is that access to `/index.html` return 404

Comment: Try changing the **ROOT_URI = ""; i.e. EMPTY STRING**. I have also faced some similar issue, also double check that in your appengine logs, how the appengine in creating and deploying your war file.

Comment: I also tried this and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently added this "index.html" test

- https://github.com/capedwarf/capedwarf-blue/blob/master/testsuite/src/test/java/org/jboss/test/capedwarf/testsuite/servlet/test/PokeTest.java#L65

and it works as it should.

Comment: Restlet works in Capedwarf for other Restlet target type, but I guess the issue is with the 'Directory' is trying to access static files which is restricted?

Comment: Here http://git.io/r34Jbg is the new Capedwarf restlet quickstart that I can't make to work. Perhaps if you have time you can try to deploy it and see if it really works